# How to loop over model attributes and use them as symbols else where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to loop over a the attr_accessor-able variables in an `ActiveModel::Model` and then fetch corresponding records from the db based on them, the problem is that it's not finding the record.

```
class DeployOptionForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :revision_number
end
```

And this is the code I was trying to get them.

```
dof.instance_variables.each do |var_sym|
  dof_var = dof.instance_variable_get(var_sym)
  var_sym.to_s.slice!(0).to_sym
  doe = DeployOption.new
  doe.value = dof_var
  doe.deploy_option_type = DeployOptionType.find_by name: var_sym
  doe.deploy = @deploy
  doe.save
end
```

I know that if I do
`doe.deploy_option_type = DeployOptionType.find_by name: :revision_number`
the record is found just fine but I'm trying to make it more adaptable.

So what do I need to do to `var_sym` to be able to do `DeployOptionType.find_by name: var_sym` ?

Comment: what's wrong with what you have currently, are you getting any error??

Comment: Ah sorry yes, it's not finding the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

Ended up having to do this

```
    var_sym = var_sym.to_s
    var_sym.slice!(0)
    var_sym = var_sym.to_sym
```

EDIT:
Actually this is a better solution and does it in 1 line!

`var_sym = var_sym.to_s.slice(1..-1).to_sym`

Comment: Accept @meager's answer it is same as what you posted

Comment: Indeed, this is what I told you to do in my answer. Whether you do it on three lines, or one line, our answers are identical.

Comment: @bjhaid no it doesn't it returns '@'

Comment: @bjhaid slice and slice! return the sliced value, so you're calling to_sym only on the first character, the one I want to remove

Answer (score 1):

`var_sym.to_s.slice!(0).to_sym` isn't doing anything. `var_sym` will be exactly what it was before you did all that.

You need `var_sym = var_sym.to_s.slice(0).to_sym`

Comment: @GabrielBaker accept this answer it is same as what you posted as yours

Comment: No this ones return '@'

Comment: @meagar slice and slice! return the sliced value, so you're calling to_sym only on the first character, the one I want to remove